# Why is making my hover button a link causing problems with the dropdown content?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a two-tiered dropdown menu where I can hover over a button in my navbar, creating a dropdown menu. My code works fine when the top layer buttons aren't links, but when I put an  tag around them it just doesn't work.

https://jsfiddle.net/wollie_/s40mucLy/3/

html:

```html
  <body style="background-color:white;">

    <div class="navbar">
    
    
    
    <div class = "dropdown">
      <a href="index.html" class = "inner-drop"><button class = "dropbtn">doesn't work-no dropdown
      </button></a>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <a><button class="dropbtn">works-no dropdown
          </button></a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a class = "inner-drop" href="pizza.html">Pizza</a>
          <a class = "inner-drop" href="cheeseburger.html">Cheeseburger</a>
          <a class = "inner-drop"href="ramen.html">Ramen</a>
          <a class = "inner-drop" href="dog-fried-rice.html">Dog Fried Rice</a>
        </div>
      </div> 
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">  Desserts
          </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="egg-tarts.html">Egg Tarts</a>
          <a href="tiramisu.html">Tiramisu</a>
          <a href="mooncake.html">Mooncakes</a>
          <a href="red-bean-buns.html">Red Bean Bun</a>
          <a href="cheesecake.html">Cheesecake</a>
          <a href="ice-cream.html">Ice Cream</a>
          <a href="cupcake.html">Cupcakes</a>
        </div>
      </div> 
    
     
    </div>


  </body>
```

css:

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;

}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

First dropdown menu has an  tag but is blotted out by the dropdown question on hover. Second menu works but doesn't have an  tag.

I would also like to know how to center the navigation buttons in the middle of the page if possible.

I tried editing the css but I can't tell what seems to be the problem. I need to have the dropdown button also have a link to its own page.

IMPORTANT: THIS IS FOR A SCHOOL PROJECT AND CODE.ORG DOESN'T ALLOW JS. I've already tried that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your css instead of `.navbar a {` use `.dropdown > *:not(:first-child) {`. When you style links using `.navbar a {` selector, every link inside navbar gets styled (including the ones with a button), using `.dropdown > *:not(:first-child) {` you style every link inside ".dropdown" container insted of the first one which is the one with the button. Regarding the centering of the buttons you can just add `display: flex` and `justify-content: center` to your .navbar class.

Comment: I agree, maybe changing the names of the css classes for the different components will help as well